# Site don't reset scale after change viewport on iOS 13

Tags: javascript, html, ios, viewport, meta-tags

I have a site with this base viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

On one page of the site we show iframe with a third-party site. On this page we're changing viewport to device-width, so that the third-party site can show a responsive site with the right device width (otherwise the site looks zoomed out)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

But when going back from the page with viewport `device-width` to viewport `width=640` the page renders zoomed in. Like the scale is too big, and not reset properly.

It should looks like this:

[image]

But renders so:

[image]

If I define `height=device-height`:

[image]

On other iOS it works well (I have tried 12 and 11).

Same behavior when basic viewport is `width=device-width, initial-scale=0.6` and viewport of page with iframe is `width=device-width, initial-scale=1`, same with `width=640` and `width=${window.scale.width / 640}`.

The bug persisted both in mobile Chrome and Safari, and sometimes goes away after a site reload.

Has anybody faced this issue, and know how I can mitigate it?